# The proper way to dispose Excel com object using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, com

I have following code (obtained from online tutorial). The code is working but I suspect the way to dispose the Excel com object is somewhat **not proper**. Do we need really need to call GC.Collect? Or what is the best way to dispose this Excel com object?

```
Public Sub t1()
    Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text)

    'select WorkSheet based on name
    Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet = CType(oBook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
    Try

        oExcel.Visible = False
        'now showing the cell value
        MessageBox.Show(oWS.Range(TextBox6.Text).Text)

        oBook.Close()
        oExcel.Quit()

        releaseObject(oExcel)
        releaseObject(oBook)
        releaseObject(oWS)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly clean up Excel interop objects in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Petr Abdulin, C# is a foreign language to me. Not duplicate exactly. I even struggle to understand the accepted answer in the so called duplicate.

Comment: You should never *need* to call `GC.Collect()`

Comment: @Seph, is that required to call 'releaseObject() Sub' in order to dispose the Excel com object?

Comment: @PanPizza http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

Comment: @PetrAbdulin C# does not have "ME" namespace, VB.Net per se cant be deployed on Linux, sounds different to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@PanPizza C# and VB.NET are very similar, remove the `;` from the end of the line, `Worksheets sheets = ...` becomes `Dim sheets Worksheets = ...`. If you're interested in getting better at programming you should really learn how to transition between both as many .NET examples are only provided in one or the other and you are really limiting yourself.

As mentioned in this answer: [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp) "Never use two dots" this means always step down into a single sub-object and never do this `Dim oWS AS Excel.Worksheet = oExcel.Worksheets.Open(...)` always step down to workbook and then step down to the worksheet, never directly from the `Excel.Application`.

As a general rule what you need to do is release your items in the reverse order to that which they were created. Otherwise you're taking the feet out from underneath your other references and they won't correctly deallocate.

Notice how you create Excel Application (`oExcel`), then Excel Workbook (`oBook`) and then finally Excel Worksheet (`oWS`), you need to release them in the reverse order.

Thus your code becomes:

```
    oBook.Close()
    oExcel.Quit()

    releaseObject(oWS)
    releaseObject(oBook)
    releaseObject(oExcel)
Catch ex As Exception
```

and just remove this code entirely from the `Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)`

```
Finally
    GC.Collect()
```

It's not needed, GC occurs naturally and don't expect your applications to instantly free up memory, .NET pools unallocated memory so that it can readily instance objects in this memory rather than having to ask the OS for more memory.

Comment: @Seph I like'd your root ref explanation but with VSTO it goes a little further than that: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop

Comment: @Seph Thanks for the comments. I agree that `GC.Collect()` is not necessary in most cases because it occurs naturally, but sometimes when you are working with COM objects, it is necessary. For me, after releasing all the objects I had to call `GC.Collect()` followed by `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. There are some comments [here](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/) about it.

Answer (score 10):

First - you *never* have to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...)` or `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(...)` when doing Excel interop. It is a confusing anti-pattern, but any information about this, including from Microsoft, that indicates you have to manually release COM references from .NET is incorrect. The fact is that the .NET runtime and garbage collector correctly keep track of and clean up COM references. For your code, this means you can remove the whole `releaseObject(...)` Sub and calls to it.

Second, if you want to ensure that the COM references to an out-of-process COM object is cleaned up when your process ends (so that the Excel process will close), you need to ensure that the Garbage Collector runs. You do this correctly with calls to `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. Calling twice is safe, end ensures that cycles are definitely cleaned up too.

Third, when running under the debugger, local references will be artificially kept alive until the end of the method (so that local variable inspection works). So a `GC.Collect()` calls are not effective for cleaning object like `rng.Cells` from the same method. You should split the code doing the COM interop from the GC cleanup into separate methods.

The general pattern would be:

```
Sub WrapperThatCleansUp()

    ' NOTE: Don't call Excel objects in here... 
    '       Debugger would keep alive until end, preventing GC cleanup

    ' Call a separate function that talks to Excel
    DoTheWork()

    ' Now Let the GC clean up (twice, to clean up cycles too)
    GC.Collect()    
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()    
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

End Sub

Sub DoTheWork()
    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim book As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    app.Visible = True
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        worksheet.Cells.Range("A" & i).Value = "Hello"
    Next
    book.Save()
    book.Close()
    app.Quit()

    ' NOTE: No calls the Marshal.ReleaseComObject() are ever needed
End Sub
```

There is a lot of false information and confusion about this issue, including many posts on MSDN and on StackOverflow.

What finally convinced me to have a closer look and figure out the right advice was this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous/ together with finding the issue with references kept alive under the debugger on some StackOverflow answer.

Comment: This is interesting because when studying opinion on this topic this is the first I have ever seen an example like yours. It seems the anti-pattern is rampant in examples.

Comment: Using GC as described here worked much better for me than System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal as described elsewhere on SO. This answer is better.

Comment: One of the few answers out there which actually work correctly. I also dispose the worksheet used in the sub.

Answer (score 1):

The key for me was to let the GarbageCollector (GC) know I wanted something cleaned up. I realize this usually isn't necessary, but when working with COM objects, it is sometimes necessary. See this link for more information https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/

After releasing the objects, ask the `GC` to clean up by calling `Collect()` and  `WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. The link above states it is necessary to call these mehtods twice in order to completely remove COM objects from memory. In my case, calling these methods once worked, but it may be worth calling it twice.

```
oBook.Close()
oExcel.Quit()

releaseObject(oExcel)
releaseObject(oBook)
releaseObject(oWS)

GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and searched for this and even Microsoft's own solution doesn't work ([Here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q317109) if you want to have a look). I have a vb.net application that exports data to an Excel template. Ideally when the user closes the Excel window it would kill the process but it doesn't because, as stated in the Microsoft article, vb.net is still referencing it.

You need to kill the process yourself, there is a procedure to do this as below:

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
     If p.ProcessName = "EXCEL.EXE" Then p.Kill
Next
```

However, this would kill all instances of Excel and the user may have other Excel windows open that would get shutdown without saving, so I've come up with this (the workbook I'm using is called "Top 5 Issues Template"):

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
     If InStr(p.MainWindowTitle, "Top 5 Issues Template") <> 0 Then p.Kill
Next
```

This looks by the window name, not process name, and kills only the process that is related to it. This is the only way I could get Excel to close properly without messing anything up.

Comment: This is a nasty hack that kills the process from the OS without de-allocating the objects you used to create those processes. This will result in null objects that will throw exceptions next time they are used.