# Application not released from Task Manager

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to write some data from my windowsform into a `Excel` file, this works.

```
        ' Excel load data
    Dim oExcelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim oWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim oWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    oWorkBook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")
    oWorkSheet = oWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

    oWorkSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Test"

    oWorkBook.Save()
    oWorkBook.Close()
```

Problem is: When I am done `Excel` is still running in my task manager. When I press the button like 10 times there are 10 `Excel` references in my task manager.

Question: How can I fully unload `Excel` after writing the value into the `Excel`?

Comment: There is already an answer here: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit**. Please check it out it has great information pertaining why this happens, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Quit` Microsoft Excel and then release the objects.

**Code referenced from this answer: [The proper way to dispose Excel com object using VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309365/the-proper-way-to-dispose-excel-com-object-using-vb-net) and [Excel application not quitting after calling quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit)**

```
'Excel load data
Dim oExcelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim oWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim oWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

oWorkBook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")
oWorkSheet = oWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

oWorkSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Test"

oWorkBook.Save()
oWorkBook.Close()

oExcelApp.Quit()

'Release object references.
releaseObject(oWorkSheet)
releaseObject(oWorkBook)
releaseObject(oExcelApp)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain in your answer **why this happens and why you need to call `ReleaseComObject`** that way other people know what causes this issue.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309365/the-proper-way-to-dispose-excel-com-object-using-vb-net) questions.

Comment: I know where to look it was my question :) I asked you to explain. If you can't `please cite your sources!`

Comment: Thanks for all great advice, and references. Now onto the next hurdle ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the connection you just opened. You can do this by adding this line after your current code:

```
oExcelApp.Quit();
```

Source & more information: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application_methods.aspx)

More information about the `quit()` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit.aspx).

Important: if you have open workbooks that are not saved yet, this method will show a dialog box asking to save.

If you don't want this, you either have to (1): save all open workbooks or (2) setting `DisplayAlerts` to false.

(1)

```
workbooks.Save()
```

(2)

```
oExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false
```

Comment: I added the oExcelApp.Quit() at the end. But still i can see the Excel in my task manager?

Comment: Give me a moment, creating a test-application myself to check.