# Closing word when using interop library - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop

I have successfully been able to convert a word doc to pdf - but I can't get the winword process to end.

```
 Dim wordApplication As Object = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim wordDocument As Object
    wordApplication.displayalerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
    wordDocument = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    'wordDocument = Nothing
    Dim outputFilename As String
    Dim filename As String

    filename = "c:\TestInvoice.doc"

    Try
        wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=False)
        outputFilename = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "pdf")

        If Not wordDocument Is Nothing Then
            wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(outputFilename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, False, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 0, 0, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, True, True, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, True, True, False)
        End If
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

        If File.Exists(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "pdf")) Then
            MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "pdf"))
        End If
        'wordDocument = Nothing

        'wordApplication.Documents(filename).Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)

        'wordDocument.dispose()

        'wordApplication.quit(False)
        wordDocument.close()

        wordApplication.application.quit(False)
        wordApplication = Nothing
```

I've tried pretty much everything and have been scratching my head for the past few days - can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The proper way to dispose Excel com object using VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309365/the-proper-way-to-dispose-excel-com-object-using-vb-net) - in particular, please see [the answer by Govert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111107/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton - unfortunately have tried all of that - but could not get the releaseObject to work - it is not recognized

Comment: If you look at the answer by Govert it shows you how to do it. Also, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45650494/1115360) to a different question which used Govert's answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit this might help you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think I understand what you are saying correct me if I'm wrong i need to  create a sub that first calls the sub that deals with the word document then, after finishing its workload it will call garbage collection

Comment: @SyedAbbas Yes, that way works in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Using statement?

Try wrapping everything in this.

```
Using wordApplication As Object = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

End Using
```

Comment: thank you for responding - I get an error on the End using line 
Invalidcast exception 0x80004002
unable to cas COM object type Microsoft.office.Interop.Word.applicationclass to interface type System.idisposable

Comment: OK, sorry for misleading you, it appears that it does not implement iDisposable.