# Workbooks.Open causes memory leak

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks

In production vba, when opening excel file in a specific folder in loop I saw excel devours memory and finally causes a memory leak. I wrote short codes to investigate its root cause and facing the following questions.

**Question.1**

In loop it just opens and closes workbook but excel's memory usage increases. It seems some object is not released but I don't understand (a) which one is and (b) what's the problem of this code.

```vb
Sub Test01()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim f As File
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Files As Variant
    Set Files = fso.GetFolder("*****").Files
    For Each f In Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Question.2**

I found that a use of COM object can be a solution. Indeed it starts another process and its memory usage never shows weird increase but I don't understand its reason because codes in loop are almost identical. Why this code doesn't lead a memory leak?

```vb
Sub Test02()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim f As File
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Dim oxl As Excel.Application
    Set oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oxl.Visible = False

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Files As Variant
    Set Files = fso.GetFolder("*****").Files
    For Each f In Files
        Set wb = oxl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next
    oxl.Application.Quit
    Set oxl = Nothing

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please note that;

1. folder contains 3000 excel files so that loop is done 3000 times
2. file size of excel files is less than 15kb

**Detailed response to [@braX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041920/workbooks-open-causes-memory-leak#comment102485148_58041920)**

I think you answered to Question.2 and intended a code like this. I understand that storing `oxl.Workbooks` improves performance than calling `oxl.Workbooks` every time, but in a perspective of memory usage it seems like a different story because `Workbooks` should be released out of the loop.

```vb
    Dim wbs as Workbooks
    Set wbs = oxl.Workbooks
    Dim Files As Variant
    Set Files = fso.GetFolder("*****").Files
    For Each f In Files
        Set wb = wbs.Open(f.Path)
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next
    Set wbs = Nothing
    oxl.Application.Quit
    Set oxl = Nothing
```

Comment: Well if there's a memory leak, doesn't it make complete and total sense that nuking the host process at every iteration *doesn't* leak any memory?

Comment: You arent setting the `Workbooks` collection to an object that you can set to `Nothing` when you are done with it. Try adding that in and killing it off at the right time as well.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm afraid not being able to understand your comment. I hopefully would like you to use more plain expression. 

Comment: @braX Thank you for letting me know that `Workbooks` is an object that can be released. But the issue still exists. I think `Workbooks` should be released when loop is done.

Comment: Have a look at this. It may help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309365/the-proper-way-to-dispose-excel-com-object-using-vb-net (although it is for .NET, the principles are similar)

Comment: There is also a method (found somewhere here on stackoverflow) that lets you create a list of current Excel processes when you start, and then when the code is done, it will kill the Excel processes that are not in that list.

Comment: @Mathieu re _that nuking the host process at every iteration doesn't leak_ but they aren't. It's nukes outside the For loop.  (But that may hide the leak)

Comment: @takuya are you sure example 2 hasn't leaked before `oxl.Application.Quit`? (Put a break on that line and check memory use before executing it)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Exactly, thank you for pointing it out! I corrected my question.

Comment: @chrisneilsen It's just a typo, sorry for confusing.

Comment: @chrisneilsen In example 2 there's no leak. As it takes time to complete I sometimes observe its memory usage.

Comment: @Takuya FWIW, I can confirm I have reproduced your observations - Test1 memory increases over time, Test2 does not apear to (I say _apear_ as memory does fluctuate, but I don't observe a rising trend).  I can't offer any explanation...