# Memory usage increases when excel doesn't respond

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks

*forked from [Workbooks.Open causes memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041920/)*

## Background

I'm investigating a cause of memory leak happened on the following code and found that it happens when excel doesn't respond. After a while running this code I see excel's process is 'not responding' on task manager and process starts devouring memory.

```vb
Sub Test01()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim f As File
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Files As Variant
    Set Files = fso.GetFolder("*****").Files
    For Each f In Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I add `DoEvents` in loop excel never freezes and memory usage increases slowly.

```vb
    For Each f In Files
        DoEvents
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next
```

## Question

Why memory usage increases when process is freezing?

## Remarks

Please note that;

1. folder contains 3000 excel files so that loop is done 3000 times
2. file size of excel files is less than 15kb

Comment: Seems you’re in the same spot as this guy here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29017231/Excel-2010-Not-releasing-memory-when-workbooks-closed.html. They mention the use of arrays of arrays and that could cause the memory flaw.

Comment: Maybe because you are trying to open a file when the path hasn't been defined. This line `Set = Workbooks.Open(fPath)`  should have errors cause nowhere have you defined `fPath`. If you would have used `Option Explicit` or `Compile`..........

Comment: @alowflyingpig that was a typo OP repeated from their other post.  I can [confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041920/workbooks-open-causes-memory-leak#comment102505344_58041920) the issue the OP describes is real.

Comment: @alowflyingpig Sorry I corrected my question as it's just a typo.

Comment: @chris You're exactly right, thank you for taking a look at this too.