# How to export data from PostgreSQL database to excel sheet? using vb.net 2019 windows form

Tags: excel, vb.net, postgresql

I have this button that when the user click all data from postgres will download to excel. i found the reference but the problem is its C# http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Try
            Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=YouthRecord;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=*****;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=*****;password=*****;"),
                    cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM ""YouthApp_table_residencedata"" ", MyCon)
                MyCon.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

                ???????
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**UPDATE** did i do it right? can you point out the mistake I made here?

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    'Create the QueryTable    
    Dim sNWind As String
    Dim oQryTable As Object
    sNWind = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Samples\Northwind.mdb"
    Try
        Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=YouthRecord;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=postgres;password=ncf123;"),
                cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM ""YouthApp_table_residencedata"" ", MyCon)
            MyCon.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            oQryTable = oSheet.QueryTables.Add(MyCon, oSheet.Range("A1"), dt)

            oQryTable.Refresh



            'Save the Workbook and Quit Excel    
            oBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\Kevin Trinidad\Documents\Residence.xls")
            oExcel.Quit


        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

this is the error i received

[image]

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
'local.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: local.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. 
The program '[39712] local.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: There are some good online conversion tools [C# to VB](https://converter.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Try
            Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
            Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer
            xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
            xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
            For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
                For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                    For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
                    Next
                Next
            Next
            Dim fName As String = "DataBuku"
            Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog
                sfd.Title = "Save As"
                sfd.OverwritePrompt = True
                sfd.FileName = fName
                sfd.DefaultExt = ".xlsx"
                sfd.Filter = "Excel Workbook(*.xlsx)|"
                sfd.AddExtension = True
                If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(sfd.FileName)
                    xlWorkBook.Close()
                    xlApp.Quit()
                    releaseObject(xlApp)
                    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
                    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
                    MsgBox("Export Successfully !", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "== Notice ==")
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReleaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

here's the link https://www.nosware.com/web/how-to-export-datagridview-items-to-excel-vb-net/463/

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WrapperToGetRidOfExcel()
    MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub
```

The code begins with calling `WrapperToGetRidOfExcel` where we call the method that contains the Excel code. This clean up code was provided by Govert (15.1k) at [The proper way to dispose Excel com object using VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309365/the-proper-way-to-dispose-excel-com-object-using-vb-net)

The `FillExcelFromDataTable` begins by calling `GetWorksheetData` which returns a DataTable.

```
Private Function GetWorksheetData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Try
        Using MyCon As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Top 10 * FROM Coffees", MyCon)
            MyCon.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function
```

You can do the appropriate replacements for you Postgres database.

Back to `FillExcelFromDataTable`.

```
Private Sub FillExcelFromDataTable()
    Dim dt = GetWorksheetData()
    Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Dim oSheet = DirectCast(oBook.Worksheets.Add, Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim ColumnIndex = 1
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns 'This loop adds the header row
        oSheet.Cells(1, ColumnIndex) = col.ColumnName
        ColumnIndex += 1
    Next
    ColumnIndex = 1 'The columns and rows in the spreadsheet
    Dim RowIndex = 2 'The columns and rows in the spreadsheet
    For rowI = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            oSheet.Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex) = dt(rowI)(col)
            ColumnIndex += 1
        Next
        ColumnIndex = 1 'Reset back to the first column
        RowIndex += 1
    Next
    oBook.Save()
    oBook.SaveAs(Filename:="ExcelDat.xlsx") 'Saved to "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\ExcelDat.xlsx"
    oBook.Close()
    oExcel.Quit()
End Sub
```

Don't `Dim` objects `As Object`. `Object` has very few properties and methods and nothing useful to you here. Hold your cursor over oExcel, oBook and oSheet. Your will see that they all have a datatype where you can use properties and methods of Excel objects.