# Files return to previous version after closing developed software

Tags: vb.net

I developed a small software that, upon installation, contains some Excel files. Within the software, these are updated from time to time or when the user requires it. I do this in the following way.

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object

'Start a new workbook in Excel
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

DeleteFilesInsideFolder("C:\Users\Public\Documents\")

oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("https://test.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/TEST/TestA.xlsx")
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks("TestA.xlsx").Activate
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks(1).SaveAs("C:\Users\Public\Documents\TestA.xlsx")
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks("TestA.xlsx").Close

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

oExcel.Quit()
```

The problem is that when the update finishes, if for example the file has a creation date of 10/22/2023 and is updated to 10/30/2023 when the software is closed, these files return to 10/22/2023 so It is automatic, and it is as if it had never been updated.

In this case, check the ***Project Properties->Publish->Update*** and disable checking for new versions.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Checking, this change of files to previous versions ***happens when the software starts again, not when it closes***. When you start the software, a screen appears that has a message that says ***"Gathering required information"*** and that's when the version returns.

Any ideas?

Comment: aren't you deleting everything in the user's public documents folder? not sure you want to do that

Comment: @BryanDellinger There is a more complete route inside it, I left it alone just to put a route. Thank you :)

Comment: You could try it the way shown in this answer to [The proper way to dispose Excel com object using VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111107/1115360)

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for your answer, Thanks, I already checked the .Close and .Quit part, and also added the releaseObject part, but it still does the same thing. Any idea?

Comment: @LARC Do you mean the file creation date in the filesystem or the file creation date in File -> Info within Excel? If the former, does the file modified date get changed correctly?

Comment: @AndrewMorton is the file creation date in the file system, but check my answer, I found the error and was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because you are not using the obook variable properly.

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object

'Start a new workbook in Excel
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

DeleteFilesInsideFolder("C:\Users\Public\Documents\")

oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("https://test.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/TEST/TestA.xlsx")
oBook.Activate
oBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\Public\Documents\TestA.xlsx")
oBook.Close

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

oExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: but SET and LET are no longer supported, in fact if I put it in the code, it gives me an error. Any other idea?. Thank you :)

Comment: oops sorry I thought this was vba - you still are not using the obook variable properly however

Comment: no problem, thank you for your time and effort. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The error was in the setup part at the time of generating it. When I generate the setup, it contains a file, for example, called Test.xlsx, but when I called it from the SharePoint platform, it was saved as TestA.xlsx. What this caused was that when I closed and opened the setup again development, it detected that there was a change in the original installed files and automatically activated the ***"Gathering Required Information"*** of the installation from MSI. What this causes is that the same software restores the original files and deletes the new files installed and/or downloaded even if they have the same names but with a different creation date on the system.

The solution was to check in the

***"EventViewer application (Local) -> Windows Log -> Application"***

there it showed me the name of the files (and their path) that had an existence error or that were corrupt

[image]

and thus review each installation file and validate the names downloaded from Sharepoint, so that they match, also, verify that the files that are no longer used in the development, remove them from the setup so that they do not generate conflicts when downloading from the platform .

Thank you all for the support, effort and time you dedicated to your answers.